Flutter build Error: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'
When I build my Flutter app for release using flutter build appbundle or just apk using flutter build apk, I see this error:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

What's the fix?

To fix this issue, delete the build folder from your project file.
Here's what mine looks like:
C:\Users\Admin\Developer\VSCProjects\Project_Name\

Then try building the app for release again, ie using flutter build appbundle
